# Downloading from Dropbox with with Ruby API

Tags: ruby, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm currently using the [futuresimple dropbox api](https://github.com/futuresimple/dropbox-api) gem in a command line Dropbox app.

Right now, I'm having second thoughts about the way I'm downloading files. The code looks like this:

```
begin
contents = env['dropbox-client'].download env['download_file_name']
rescue Dropbox::API::Error::NotFound => e
  say "File Not Found! Could not download", :red
  exit 1
rescue Dropbox::API::Error => e
  say "Connection to Dropbox failed (#{e})", :red
  exit 1
end

File.open(env['download_file_name'], 'w') {|f| f.write(contents) }
```

I feel like this code can be improved.

My basic question is:

Is there a more nuanced way to take the body from the API request from dropbox in `contents` and use it to create a file better than the way I've done here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

```
File.open(env['download_file_name'], 'w') {|f| f.write(contents) }
```

Can be more clearly written:

```
File.write(env['download_file_name'], contents)
```

And try this untested code:

```
rescue Dropbox::API::Error::NotFound, Dropbox::API::Error => e
  msg = if (e == Dropbox::API::Error::NotFound)
    "File Not Found! Could not download" 
  else
    "Connection to Dropbox failed (#{e})"
  end

  say msg, :red
  exit 1
end
```

(I'm in a hurry but it looks right.)

Comment: Hi! The code is cleaner, but I was more thinking of if there was a better way of taking an http body and writing it to file. If File.write is the best way I'll use that :)

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding a simpler and/or better way of writing to a file than `File.write`.